# Is it possible to use the front and back camera in react-native in the same time?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-camera

I use the npm package react-native-camera and I would like to have a view like when you have a WhatsApp video-call, but just with your own cameras.

I want my back camera in fullscreen and the front camera as a small component over the other one.

This is in my render() method:

```
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <RNCamera
        style={styles.back}
        type={RNCamera.constants.Type.back}>
    </RNCamera>
    <RNCamera
        style={styles.front}
        type={RNCamera.constants.Type.front}>
    </RNCamera>
  </View>
);
```

But there is always just the first camera running.

It's on MacOS and I run it on a device, an iPhone SE.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [AVFoundation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW25), from Apple, it does not seem to be possible:

> **Note:** Media capture does not support simultaneous capture of both the front-facing and back-facing cameras on iOS devices.

Comment: is it still relevant

Comment: @DaniilKunin I believe Apple and Android now have a version of Multicam but not sure if someone has added the feature to RN: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/capture_setup/avmulticampip_capturing_from_multiple_cameras

Did you find a way?